# How to retrieve the dataproc job output driver logs through REST API

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

Hi I want to retrieve the console logs of a dataproc job from API. I don't seem to find a way as all the options are there from the cloud logging. I wanted to retrieve the console logs and then perform some search to find a particular word that if present, I have to flag the job.